# changing angle in 3d scatterplot?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I drew a 3D scatterplot in R which is a flat surface.

But the plot does not clearly show what it looks like, so I'd like to change the angle to see this plot at a different viewpoint.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: To **see** on your screen or to **print** in a file?

Comment: Both. Does it matter?

Comment: It might. Please share your code to see which package you use.

Comment: are you looking for the `angle=` parameter to `scatterplot3d` ?

Comment: I'm using scatterplot3d package

Comment: Yes. angle= parameter works.